# I need to get an item from array by index defined in a variable (Handlebars.js)

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I have an array and I need to access it depending on a variable.

This one works:

```
<h4>{{subject.1.name}}</h4>
```

I need to have a variable to access it in this manner:

```
var a = 1;
...
<h4>{{subject.a.name}}</h4>
```

Is it possible? Where should I declare the variable?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Subject doesn't have `a` it's just a variable you declared.

Answer (score 0):

There is two way to access property of any object in `JavaScript` using `dot` and [] and `handlebar` support both in `template`.

```
<h4>{{subject.[a].name}}</h4>
```

Comment: Where should I declare the variable?